# .htaccess inheritance issue between root and sud domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I seem to be having a .htaccess inheritance issue - I'm not too sure how to stop it as not needed to before - I have one `.htaccess` file in the `/home/x/public_html/` folder, and I've also got another `.htaccess` file in a sub-folder `/home/x/public_html/beta/` folder - which appears as the subdomain **beta.mydomain.com**

It is quite noticeable, as the password prompt appears on the sub-domain, and if doing `print_r($_GET)` can see specific variables to each `.htaccess` file

**public_html/ .htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
    RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^400/$ /index.php?error=400
    RewriteRule ^401/$ /index.php?error=401
    RewriteRule ^403/$ /index.php?error=403
    RewriteRule ^404/$ /index.php?error=404
    RewriteRule ^408/$ /index.php?error=408
    RewriteRule ^500/$ /index.php?error=500

    RewriteRule ^/?css/.+$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?img/.+$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?js/.+$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1&front=yes [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 400 /400/
ErrorDocument 401 /401/
ErrorDocument 403 /403/
ErrorDocument 404 /404/
ErrorDocument 408 /408/
ErrorDocument 500 /500/

AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /home/x/public_html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

**public_html/beta/ .htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Add the trailing slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
    RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]

########## BASE URLS ##########

# Error Re-Direction
    RewriteRule ^400/$ /index.php?error=400
    RewriteRule ^401/$ /index.php?error=401
    RewriteRule ^403/$ /index.php?error=403
    RewriteRule ^404/$ /index.php?error=404
    RewriteRule ^408/$ /index.php?error=408
    RewriteRule ^500/$ /index.php?error=500

# Content Re-Direction
    RewriteRule ^/?css/.+$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?img/.+$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?js/.+$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?_data/.+$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1&front=no [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

########## CATCH ERRORS ##########

ErrorDocument 400 /400/
ErrorDocument 401 /401/
ErrorDocument 403 /403/
ErrorDocument 404 /404/
ErrorDocument 408 /408/
ErrorDocument 500 /500/
```

The error pages, image folders, etc, are different for both sites - I've tried changing the rewrite base on the sub-domain to the full root path to it, this did not work either. I'm probably doing something very wrong causing inheritance to happen

It may work if the first .htaccess file stopped processing rules if the subdomain was detected, though I'm a bit unsure if you can do that or not

I do hope this isn't a stupid question, as not had an inheritance issue before

Comment: So what’s the actual “error” – only the password protection of the subdomain, or something else? If only that, then `ALLOW` and `SATISFY` help fix that.

Comment: I discovered the error as having trouble setting a `$_SESSION` and storing data in PHP - I believe they're related somehow

Comment: Then check the PHP session settings (phpinfo).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the session settings - I've check via `phpinfo()` - the point is, I would like the subdomain's .htaccess file working only on the subdomain - I do not want the subdomain to be using the root's .htaccess file

Comment: Then you will have to place your subdomain’s _folder_ outside of the root folder.

Comment: @MrJ: Can you check your `VirtualHost` config and see what is `DocumentRoot` value for your sub domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There's nothing wrong with the session settings - I've check via phpinfo() - the point is, I would like the subdomain's .htaccess file working only on the subdomain - I do not want the subdomain to be using the root's .htaccess file

The subdomain's htaccess file *isn't* using the root's htaccess. The problem is that you are routing things to the document root instead of the subdomain. Error document statements need the full path to the file, you're sending it to the document root. And you need to change your rewrite base:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /beta/

# Add the trailing slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
    RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]

########## BASE URLS ##########

# Error Re-Direction
    RewriteRule ^400/$ index.php?error=400
    RewriteRule ^401/$ index.php?error=401
    RewriteRule ^403/$ index.php?error=403
    RewriteRule ^404/$ index.php?error=404
    RewriteRule ^408/$ index.php?error=408
    RewriteRule ^500/$ index.php?error=500

# Content Re-Direction
    RewriteRule ^/?css/.+$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?img/.+$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?js/.+$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?_data/.+$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1&front=no [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

########## CATCH ERRORS ##########

ErrorDocument 400 /beta/400/
ErrorDocument 401 /beta/401/
ErrorDocument 403 /beta/403/
ErrorDocument 404 /beta/404/
ErrorDocument 408 /beta/408/
ErrorDocument 500 /beta/500/
```

Comment: Hmmm... I thought I tried this, but seems to be working now... perhaps I had a slight typo or was cached - thanks for your help :o)